# Power View gallery get url for one report

Tags: sharepoint-addin, silverlight, powerview

I tried to get the url of a single report from a Power View reports gallery (from a rdlx file). 

Till now I didn't find information about that. 
Currently I know that you can get a specific report if you add a number at the end of the url:

http://example.com/Product.rdlx&ViewMode=Presentation&ReportSection=ReportSection4

You can get a single report but it's not so clear how to get the right report for the right number. It seems a little bit random.
I hope this is my first impression. I don't understand if is alphabetic order or something different.

Anyone know what is the logic in order to obtain from the gallery a specific report?